# Can you turn your camera on in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I can't seem to turn my camera on. I checked the box but I couldn't find any AR button. Can someone tell me how to turn my camera on?

Comment: Do you have a case? That could be blocking the camera...

Comment: Does your phone have a Gyroscope?

Answer (score 4):

The AR button/toggle switch can be found when encountering wild Pokemon and on a gym's "landing page" when you are within range and can perform and action on it(train on an allied gym or battle an enemies').

Answer (score 1):

When you're catching a Pokemon you have an AR toggle in the top right corner. You need to switch it on.